# Component Development PHP Version Check

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, component, development

I've been developing a component, and have been trying to find some information, to no avail, of having my component perform a check of the PHP version before install. If PHP is greater than 7, then install. But, if PHP is less than 7 (such as 5.6) then show an error that PHP 7 is required, then stop the install.

I already figure that this will go into script.php in the preflight, but I'm struggling trying to find something to use to do the check.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Lots of components have a check like that. Here's the top of admin tools core install script eg.

```
protected $minimumPHPVersion = '5.3.3';

public function preflight($type, $parent)
    {
        // Check the minimum PHP version
        if (!version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $this->minimumPHPVersion, 'ge'))
        {
            $msg = "<p>You need PHP $this->minimumPHPVersion or later to install this package</p>";
            JLog::add($msg, JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }
....etc
```

As you can see its using both the core constant for the version, and the core function for version comparison.

Further reading:

[PHP Doc re the existance of constant PHP_VERSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

[PHP Doc on using version compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)